# I've installed golang with accordance with the wiki yet "go get" is missing

Tags: programming, golang

I've installed everything go-related from synaptic and later added ppa as described in the wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Go 
yet I cannot do "go get" for example

```
go get code.google.com/p/gorilla/mux
```

says that go command is not found.

How should I install this "go" command?

Comment: It works if you follow this procedure:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/463989/installing-the-go-language/528487#528487

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a tool that seems to be released recently. If you install the `golang-weekly` package instead of `golang-stable` (available also through the `ppa:gophers/go` PPA), you'll see that `go` is available under `/usr/bin` directory.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you follow this procedure:
[Installing the Go Language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463989/installing-the-go-language/528487#528487)

You have to modify your  ~/.bashrc as follows.

```
nano ~/.bashrc

export GOPATH=/srv/go
if [ -d "/usr/lib/go/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="${GOPATH}/bin:/usr/lib/go/bin:${PATH}"
fi
```